# Is there a way to automate an update to the document comment block of a modified method in visual studio / c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**How can I update, without discarding, a document comment after modifying a method's signature?**

tl;dr

Say I have a method like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates how many mermaids to save on our arctic cruise
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberToSave">The number of mermaids you <strong>intend</strong> to save</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool SaveTheMermaids(int numberToSave)
    {
        // Some swimmingly great code goes here.
    }
```

When I reference this method, I get some keen Intellisense like this:
[image]

OK - cool, now let's say I modify the method to include the number of sponsors in my signature, changing this:

```
public bool SaveTheMermaids(int numberToSave)
```

to this:

```
public bool SaveTheMermaids(int numberToSave, int numberOfSponsors)
```

Can I use some sort of hot-key (in visual studio) or macro (in c#) to modify the documentation comment block such that it just brings in the signature change or do I have to delete that documentation comment and rebuild it from scratch each time? Is there a plug-in or a tool for Visual Studio that needs to be installed for this?

Note that I'm just looking for a quick way to have `/// <param name="numberOfSponsors"></param>` added to the document comment, since that parameter was added after the document comment was created.

Thanks!

Comment: Resharper does this.  Code Maid *might* do this.  I don't think this can be done in vanilla VS.  You might find some Roslyn analyzers that do this, maybe.

Comment: You could use an external documentation file and include a generator as part of your build?